Sympy is struggling to evaluate an inequality relational Kronecker delta function after subbing in values to a numerical value

I'm trying to evaluate this function after subbing in all the respective values. For some reason, this function ends up stopping here and can't be evaluated further into a numerical value.
I've tried numerous combinations of simplify() and doit() without getting anywhere. Anyone have any idea on what the issue might be?
Let me know if you require more information, thanks.
I tried different combinations of simplify(), doit() etc. But can't seem to have this function evaluate into a numerical value. This function is part of an element within a matrix. All the elements similar to this function did not evaluate.
Here is a recreation of the code that produces this error:
`
from sympy import summation, Min, IndexedBase, symbols, pretty_print, Matrix, diff, ImmutableDenseMatrix

K1, K2 = symbols("K1 K2")
N_T, N_f, i, j = symbols("N_T N_f i j", integer=True, positive=True)

s_x = IndexedBase("s_x")
s_y = IndexedBase("s_y")
s_z = IndexedBase("s_z")
s_star_x = IndexedBase("s_star_x")
s_star_y = IndexedBase("s_star_y")
s_star_z = IndexedBase("s_star_z")
w = IndexedBase("w")
h = IndexedBase("h")


def norm2(vec):
    if isinstance(vec, (list, Matrix)):
        return sum(comp**2 for comp in vec)
    else:
        return vec**2


s_diff_sum = summation(
    summation(
        K1
        * norm2(
            [
                s_x[i] - s_x[j] - (s_star_x[i] - s_star_x[j]),
                s_y[i] - s_y[j] - (s_star_y[i] - s_star_y[j]),
                s_z[i] - s_z[j] - (s_star_z[i] - s_star_z[j]),
            ]
        ),
        (j, i + 1, Min(N_f, i + 3)),
    ),
    (i, 1, N_f),
)


matrix_elements = []
N_f = 8
Nt_value = 4

for t in range(N_f):
    row1 = [s_x[t]]
    row2 = [s_y[t]]
    row3 = [s_z[t]]
    matrix_elements.append(row1)
    matrix_elements.append(row2)
    matrix_elements.append(row3)

S = Matrix(matrix_elements)


matrix_elements = []


for t in range(Nt_value):
    row1 = [h[t]]
    row2 = [w[t, 1]]
    row3 = [w[t, 2]]
    row4 = [w[t, 3]]

    matrix_elements.append(row1)
    matrix_elements.append(row2)
    matrix_elements.append(row3)
    matrix_elements.append(row4)


matrix_elements.append(S)

U = Matrix(matrix_elements)

pretty_print(U)


cost_diff_U_2 = diff(s_diff_sum, U, 2)

N_T, N_f, i, j = symbols("N_T N_f i j", integer=True, positive=True)

cost_diff_U_2 = cost_diff_U_2.subs({N_f: 8, K1: 0.1})

cost_diff_U_2_reshaped = cost_diff_U_2.reshape(40 * 1 * 40 * 1)

cost_diff_U_2_reshaped = cost_diff_U_2_reshaped.reshape(40, 40)

cost_diff_U_2_reshaped = ImmutableDenseMatrix(
    cost_diff_U_2_reshaped.tolist()
)

pretty_print(cost_diff_U_2_reshaped.doit(), num_columns=200)

`

Would you please share the code?

So the problem is that it's a VERY large script with a bunch of symbolic operations happening throughout. The code used to try and evaluate the function in the image is: cost_diff_U_2_expanded_doit = cost_diff_U_2_expanded_doit.simplify().doit()
The function it's being performed on starts out being a cost function which is then partially derived by a matrix where values are then subbed into their symbolic counterparts.

cost_diff_U_2_expanded_doit = cost_diff_U_2_expanded_doit.subs(             iterative_sub_dict         )
I sub in values using the subs() function as shown above

@Rhyn155 please add your inequality, all the symbols, etc. as text so it can be copy-and-pasted, discovered, etc.

Currently busy trying to recreate the problem in a different script so I can post the code

Easier way, run this and paste the output: import sympy as sp;sp.print_python(cost_diff_U_2_expanded_doit)

I added the code now
